# Scanner.next() not blocking

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a method which should wait for the user to input a string to indicate which direction the player wants to move.

```
private static void makeMoves(java.awt.Point playerPosition,
        java.awt.Point snakePosition) {
    Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    String move = scanner.next();
    switch (move.charAt(0)) {
    case 'h':
        if (playerPosition.y == 0) {
            playerPosition.y = 9;
        } else {
            playerPosition.y = Math.max(0, playerPosition.y - 1);
        }
        moveSnake(playerPosition, snakePosition);
        break;
    case 'u':
        if (playerPosition.y == 9) {
            playerPosition.y = 0;
        } else {
            playerPosition.y = Math.min(9, playerPosition.y + 1);
        }
        moveSnake(playerPosition, snakePosition);
        break;
    case 'l':
        if (playerPosition.x == 0) {
            playerPosition.x = 9;
        } else {
            playerPosition.x = Math.max(0, playerPosition.x - 1);
        }
        moveSnake(playerPosition, snakePosition);
        break;
    case 'r':
        if (playerPosition.x == 39) {
            playerPosition.x = 0;
        } else {
            playerPosition.x = Math.min(39, playerPosition.x + 1);
        }
        moveSnake(playerPosition, snakePosition);
        break;
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

It always throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
at ZZZZZnake.makeMoves(ZZZZZnake.java:52)
at ZZZZZnake.main(ZZZZZnake.java:45)
```

According to the API the `Scanner.next()` should block but is not waiting for the user to input a direction. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using a Scanner tied to `System.in` anywhere else in your code?

Comment: No thats the only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closing the `Scanner` instance causes the underlying `InputStream` to be closed preventing input being read by subsequent calls. Remove the statement

```
scanner.close();
```

Read: [Do not create multiple buffered wrappers on a single InputStream](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/FIO06-J.+Do+not+create+multiple+buffered+wrappers+on+a+single+InputStream)

Comment: But with each call of the method I recreat it by calling `Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);` or not?

Comment: Yes but there's only one `System.in` and when that's closed no further `Scanner` instances can read from the `InputStream`

Comment: Okay and how can I prevent that?

Comment: already in the answer...as a suggested improvement I would suggest creating one `Scanner` instance at class level rather than using several potential local instances

Comment: Okay...moved it to be a class variable and worked fine. Thanks